# How to check if contacts downloaded my application?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile, expo

I'm using expo react native and I want to do something similar to whatsapp (check if contacts downloaded the app so I can give them some permissions, and if a contact doesn't have the app I can invite him).

The problem is that I don't know how to start. Where should I read the contacts? Should I return them to server-side or read them from phone ? What are key words or concept I should read about and follow to take the right path doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve it would be to get the contact list, return it to server-side (where, I presume, you keep a db of user contact numbers) and there you compare if any of those contacts matches those from your db - from server-side send back just the ones that match.

Comment: and I should send contacts each time the user opens the app ? Is that optimal ?

Comment: you can send it when the user goes to "contacts" part of your app. You can save the list of contacts that matched locally, and then sync that list in background every time